# Adding specified row for the data missing

Tags: r, bind, tibble

I want to insert 'NA' value for specified Plot, time and Date and they are located randomly. I figure out how to do manually using `add_row` function but the main concern for me is I have tons of data and doing manually doesn't help. My data are in this format.

```
Plot Date Time Canopyheight
B1 10/22/2019 22 50
B1 10/22/2019 1 80
B1 10/22/2019 4 9
```

So my in each plot, there are 4 timestamps as 22,1,4 and 6 and sometimes there is missing time stamp like `B1 10/22/2019 6 Na`. I can add these rows by using the code below

```
  add_row(agg, Date = '10/21/2019', Plot = 'BG107B2', Time = 22,
          Canopyheight = NA, .before = 1)
```

but I have several dates and plots where I need to add the row. I have tried the following codes

```r
test <- agg %>%
  mutate(ID2 = as.integer(factor(Plot, levels = unique(.$Plot)))) %>%
  split(f = .$ID2) %>%
  map_if(.p = function(x) unique(x$ID2) != unique(last(.)$ID2),
         ~bind_rows(.x, tibble(Time = unique(.x$Time), Canopyheight = NA,
                               ID2 = unique(.x$ID2)))) %>%
  bind_rows() %>%
  select(-ID2)
```

But still, I am not able to do it, is there any ways that I can automate this instead of the manual way?

Thanks and have a great day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `complete` from `tidyr` to complete the missing combination of `Time` for each `Plot`.

```
tidyr::complete(df, Plot, Date, Time = c(22, 1, 4, 6))

#  Plot  Date        Time Canopyheight
#  <fct> <fct>      <dbl>        <int>
#1 B1    10/22/2019     1           80
#2 B1    10/22/2019     4            9
#3 B1    10/22/2019     6           NA
#4 B1    10/22/2019    22           50
#5 B2    10/22/2019     1           NA
#6 B2    10/22/2019     4            9
#7 B2    10/22/2019     6           80
#8 B2    10/22/2019    22           50
```

**data**

Included one more group of `Plot` for testing the solution.

```
df <- structure(list(Plot = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("B1", 
"B2"), class = "factor"), Date = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = "10/22/2019", class = "factor"), Time = c(22L, 
1L, 4L, 22L, 6L, 4L), Canopyheight = c(50L, 80L, 9L, 50L, 80L, 
9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked finally with this code and the previous code.

Answer (score 1):

One method is actually to do a full join on the expected date/time combinations. This will naturally introduce `NA` into the remaining columns. For example:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
agg <- read.table(header=TRUE, stringsAsFactors=FALSE, text="
Plot Date Time Canopyheight
B1 10/22/2019 22 50
B1 10/22/2019 1 80
B1 10/22/2019 4 9")
distinct(agg, Plot, Date) %>%
  crossing(Time = c(22L, 1L, 4L, 6L)) %>%
  full_join(agg, ., by = c("Plot", "Date", "Time"))
#   Plot       Date Time Canopyheight
# 1   B1 10/22/2019   22           50
# 2   B1 10/22/2019    1           80
# 3   B1 10/22/2019    4            9
# 4   B1 10/22/2019    6           NA
```

The first two lines of the pipe just provide all days where you are expecting times to be included, and then we force (with `tidyr::crossing`) all combinations of `Time` with that `Plot,Date` combo:

```r
distinct(agg, Plot, Date) %>%
  crossing(Time = c(22L, 1L, 4L, 6L))
# # A tibble: 4 x 3
#   Plot  Date        Time
#   <chr> <chr>      <int>
# 1 B1    10/22/2019     1
# 2 B1    10/22/2019     4
# 3 B1    10/22/2019     6
# 4 B1    10/22/2019    22
```

The concept of *join* and *merge* with datasets can be unintuitive if you've never done it before, I suggest reading more about them elsewhere. If you're ever going to work with a SQL database, it becomes (in my opinion) even more critical a skill to refine. Some worthwhile references are below (not all about R, but concepts are still relevant):

- [What is the difference between Left, Right, Outer and Inner Joins?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/448023/3358272)
- [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38549/3358272)
- [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/3358272)
- https://www.shanelynn.ie/merge-join-dataframes-python-pandas-index-1/

Comment: Thank you so much. It worked finally. Saved a lot of time. Kudos to you and this team.